# Authentication when using Security Token Service

Tags: wcf, wif, sts-securitytokenservice

I have created a Security Token Service (STS), an service with a reference to the STS and an example desktop application.

This works as expected when using Windows authentication and Message security, a token is retrieved from the STS and the service method is called successfully.  The service returns a string containing the current users identity, which returns my AD username.

I have a requirement however to authenticate against a database rather than AD.  I have tried creating a CustomUserNameValidator (in the STS, is this the correct place?) and referencing it in the web.config.  I then provide the credentials as shown below.

`SampleServiceReference.SampleServiceClient client = new SampleServiceReference.SampleServiceClient();
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName
    = "alex";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password
    = "pass";`

I believe the certificates are set up correctly (all using 'localhost'), however I receive the following exception when calling the service:

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: ID3242: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized.

Whatever I try seems to fail.  Is what I am describing even possible?  Does the service client also pass the client credentials through to the STS, or am I completely misunderstanding what is happening here?

This stackoverflow question is similar, however I have checked the audience URL and it seems ok. [WIF STS ID3242](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223018/wif-sts-id3242-the-security-token-could-not-be-authenticated-or-authorized)

Has anyone got any advice on how I can achieve custom authentication when using a STS?

Comment: Now that I've resolved my problem I thought I'd update this in case anyone else is having similar issues.  A CustomUserNameValidator isn't what I needed, instead it was a CustomNamePasswordValidatorSecurityTokenHandler that implemented either UserNameSecurityTokenHandler or WindowsUserNameSecurityTokenHandler.  Take a look at example 4 from the solution here http://claimsid.codeplex.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: the code samples referenced below are not available anymore (Codeplex doesn't exist). The book download does and it is here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28362

---

There's a simple example of what you need here: http://claimsid.codeplex.com

Look at either sample 8 or 4.

Small clarification though. The username/password authentication is on the STS, not on your service. Your service will authenticate with a security token obtained from the STS.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Example 4 is exactly what I spent all day yesterday implementing, so this confirms that what I have done is correct.  Wish I'd found it earlier!

Comment: Thanks for answering this question. However, please give a summary of the link you posted. Links may vanish or (in my case) not be permitted access behind a company firewall.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [StarterSTS](http://startersts.codeplex.com/).

The full source code is provided and it authenticates against the standard aspnetdb roles based SQL DB. There are a number of videos to help you get it up and running.

This project was then turned into ASP MVC - [IdentityServer](http://identityserver.codeplex.com/). This isn't quite as mature wrt the help files etc.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I've come across StarterSTS already.  It's a great example of how to use a STS with membership and profile providers, however I don't believe it contains a sample of securing a WCF service using STS and username/password credentials - which seems to be my problem.

Comment: Just had a look at IdentityServer, this looks promising and might solve my problem. http://identityserver.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/57233#1154163

Comment: Yeah - 90 % of the documentation in this area is around the passive rather than the active profile. I presume you started off with the WCF STS templates in VS 2010? (the ones that come with the WIF SDK).